# Void the Default Entity Add return type result in WCF Data Services

Tags: performance, post, wcf-data-services

When an entity is added using HTTP/POST in WCF Data Services, it returns a 201 status code and also the newly added entity.

Is it possible to stop returning the newly added entity in the response.

I am looking at just using the status code to know the result of the operation and possibly minimize the data flow by doing the above.

Ponnu

Answer (score 0):

The RTM bits of WCF Data Services don't support this, but the latest CTP does. You can get it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/10/13/announcing-wcf-data-services-oct-2011-ctp-for-net-4-and-silverlight-4.aspx.
The client can then send a Prefer header to notify the server if it wants the response to contain the data or not. So for example Prefer: return-no-content will cause the server to leave the response empty (Note that this might change the status code, for example 200 with content will change to 204 with no content).

Comment: thanks Vitek. I have downloaded and used the Oct 2011 CTP like you suggested, it does not work. I still get a response entity. Here is my request if it helps, Request:`code`POST http://ipaddress/mp/v2/MAPI.svc/T HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
content-type: application/json
accept: application/json
prefer: return-no-content
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Content-Length: 309
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW5AbWlsbHMtcmVldmUuY29tO3Jk
Host: ipaddress